# Any ideas how to parse this payload in python?

Tags: python, json, parsing, data-structures, iot

I am using MQTT to subscribe to a topic and receive messages. I have this code written so far and it works fine subscribing and all but I am having problems determining a way to parse through the payload that I receive from the MQTT broker. I have been trying to obtain the numerical values that I see in the payload but I cannot figure out the right approach to parse this data. Any ideas/suggestions? Thanks!

## My Code:

there is more code that is irrelevant. this is just a snippet.

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import json

#Call back functions 

# gives connection message
def on_connect(client,userdata,rc):
print("Connected with result code:"+str(rc))
# subscribe for all devices of user
client.subscribe('+/devices/+/up')

def on_connect(client,userdata,rc):
print("Connected with result code:"+str(rc))
# subscribe for all devices of user
client.subscribe('+/devices/+/up')

def on_message(client,userdata,msg):
print"Topic",msg.topic + "\nMessage:" + str(msg.payload)

node_data = str(msg.payload)
print '\r\n test'
print node_data

j = json.loads(node_data)
print "\r\n after loads: "
print j
```

**My Outputs**:

```
Message:{"payload":"Dgv+CggGBCYFAPMLAgc=","fields":{"Light":58.32,"Pressure":98569.5,"Temp":32.4375,"X_accel":0.6875,"Y_accel":-0.125,"Z_accel":0.625},"port":1,"counter":8,"dev_eui":"000000007D9050C1","metadata":[{"frequency":904.3,"datarate":"SF7BW125","codingrate":"4/5","gateway_timestamp":2090979635,"gateway_time":"2016-07-28T02:26:15.386371Z","channel":2,"server_time":"2016-07-28T02:06:13.075194806Z","rssi":-13,"lsnr":9.5,"rfchain":0,"crc":1,"modulation":"LORA","gateway_eui":"0080000000009BE6","altitude":911,"longitude":-93.19677,"latitude":45.10303}]}


 test
{"payload":"Dgv+CggGBCYFAPMLAgc=","fields":{"Light":58.32,"Pressure":98569.5,"Temp":32.4375,"X_accel":0.6875,"Y_accel":-0.125,"Z_accel":0.625},"port":1,"counter":8,"dev_eui":"000000007D9050C1","metadata":[{"frequency":904.3,"datarate":"SF7BW125","codingrate":"4/5","gateway_timestamp":2090979635,"gateway_time":"2016-07-28T02:26:15.386371Z","channel":2,"server_time":"2016-07-28T02:06:13.075194806Z","rssi":-13,"lsnr":9.5,"rfchain":0,"crc":1,"modulation":"LORA","gateway_eui":"0080000000009BE6","altitude":911,"longitude":-93.19677,"latitude":45.10303}]}


 after loads: 
{u'fields': {u'Y_accel': -0.125, u'Temp': 32.4375, u'X_accel': 0.6875, u'Light': 58.32, u'Pressure': 98569.5, u'Z_accel': 0.625}, u'counter': 8, u'port': 1, u'dev_eui': u'000000007D9050C1', u'payload': u'Dgv+CggGBCYFAPMLAgc=', u'metadata': [{u'gateway_time': u'2016-07-28T02:26:15.386371Z', u'server_time': u'2016-07-28T02:06:13.075194806Z', u'datarate': u'SF7BW125', u'gateway_eui': u'0080000000009BE6', u'modulation': u'LORA', u'gateway_timestamp': 2090979635, u'longitude': -93.19677, u'crc': 1, u'frequency': 904.3, u'rfchain': 0, u'codingrate': u'4/5', u'lsnr': 9.5, u'latitude': 45.10303, u'rssi': -13, u'altitude': 911, u'channel': 2}]}
```

I want to be able to extract the numerical values from this...string?Dict?Json?(payload) for the 'Temp', 'Light', 'Pressure' etc...parameters.Any advice is greatly appreciated.'
I have tried the following but I receive this error. Doesn't tell me much...

```
data = json.loads(node_data)
Press = data['Pressure']
print Press
```

File "C:\Python27\My_Py_27_Codes\scratch_py_mqtt.py", line 25, in on_message
Press = data['Pressure']

```
KeyError: 'Pressure'
```

Apparently 'Pressure' is not a key in this Dictionary?

Comment: Press = data["fields"]['Pressure']

Comment: try `data['fields']['Pressure']`.

Comment: you have to give the exact location of the field. In your case 'Pressure' is inside 'fields'

Comment: Pressure is a key of one of the dictionaries... Just not the top level

Answer (score 3):

```
node_data  = {"payload":"dsgsg","fields":{"pressure":34,"temp":35}}
data = json.loads(node_data)
Press = data['fields']['Pressure']
print Press
```

you have to give the exact location of the filed. In your case `pressure`  is inside the `fields` dictionary

Comment: Yes, I was unfamiliar with this topic I guess. It was an easy fix once I realized I was indeed working with a 'Dictionary'. I solved my own issue prior to reading your comment, but I can see that you are correct. Thanks for your help and generous advice. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

So after a few hours of scratching my head and 'code-ing' away, I managed to achieve my goal. I am not sure if it is the 'prettiest' way or if it's even the best way to do it but here is what I figured out: I was dealing with a 'Dictionary' and I had to select the appropriate key-name 'fields'. This would then enable me to 'get' the numerical values associated with the parameters (Temp, Pressure, Light, etc...) that are inside the 'fields' portion of the Dictionary.

## Code to solve my issue:

```
def on_message(client,userdata,msg):
print"Topic",msg.topic + "\n\nMessage:" + str(msg.payload)

node_data = str(msg.payload)

print ' \n Sensor Values \r'

my_dict = json.loads(node_data)
params = my_dict.get("fields",None)

light = params.get('Light')
pressure = params.get('Pressure')
temp = params.get('Temp')
x = params.get('X_accel')
y = params.get('Y_accel')
z = params.get('Z_accel')

print ''
print 'Light:' + str(light)
print 'Pressure:' + str(pressure)
print 'Temperature:' + str(temp)
print 'X-accel:' + str(x)
print 'Y-accel:' + str(y)
print 'Z-accel:' + str(z)
print '\n\n'
```

## Cheers everyone!

Comment: Since all the code after this line `params = my_dict.get("fields",None)` works with params as a dict, a better default value would be `params = my_dict.get("fields",{})`.